# While parsing JSON avoid Go program from being stopped in case of any errors

Tags: go

How could I Ignore errors while parsing below JSON

Here is the sample JSON response

```
{"success":true,"endpoint":"https://api.abcxyz.com","info":
{"Guestconnected":134,"Guestratio":100000.06963,"symbol1":
{"code":"NY","symbol":"*","name":"newyear","codev":391.78161,"symbolAppearsAfter
":false,"local":true},"symbol2":
{"code":"HNY","symbol":"@","name":"HappyNewYear","codev":1000000.0960,"symbolApp
earsAfter":true,"local":false},"latest":
{"value":1597509,"autovalue":"00099cf8da58a36c08f2ef98650ff6043ddfb","height":47
4696,"time":1499527696}},"Allguest":
{"all":4,"filtered":4,"total_invitations":15430,"sent_invitations":15430,"final_
invitations":0},"Guestlist":
[{"GuestCode":"369AR","all":2,"total_invitations":5430,"sent_invitations":5430,"
final_invitations":0,"change":0,"accounts":0},
{"GuestCode":"6POIA96TY","all":2,"total_invitations":10000,"sent_invitations":10
000,"final_invitations":0,"change":0,"accounts":0}]}
```

My Code is :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)


type object struct {
    Success bool `json:"success"`
    Endpoint string `json:"endpoint"`
    Allguest struct {
        All int `json:"all"`
        Filtered int `json:"filtered"`
        TotalInvitations int `json:"total_invitations"`
        SentInvitations int `json:"sent_invitations"`
        FinalInvitations int `json:"final_invitations"`
    } `json:"Allguest"`
    Guestlist []struct {
        GuestCode string `json:"GuestCode"`
        All int `json:"all"`
        TotalInvitations int `json:"total_invitations"`
        SentInvitations int `json:"sent_invitations"`
        FinalInvitations int `json:"final_invitations"`
        Change int `json:"change"`
        Accounts int `json:"accounts"`
    } `json:"Guestlist"`
}

func Newreq(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

uri := "https://siteurl.com/api?lists=1"
res, err := http.Get(uri)
fmt.Println(uri)
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()

var s object
// Using err := gives error no new variables on left side of := during compilation ?
err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&s) 
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
fmt.Println(s.Success)
fmt.Println(s.Allguest.TotalInvitations)
for i := range s.Guestlist {
fmt.Println(s.Guestlist[i].TotalInvitations)
}
}

func main() {

http.HandleFunc("/", Newreq)

log.Println("Listening")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

The Program has been compiled and is running successfully if there is no errors in the JSON response supplied by the server .

I am testing this locally at localhost:8080

The problem is how can we ignore any error and avoid the program from stopping automatically, for example :

1. There are instances when the server at `https://siteurl.com/api?lists=1` can be down then in that case it will give error "No such host" and the program exits, how can we ignore the error and keep the program running?
2. There are instances when the server at `https://siteurl.com/api?lists=1` gives a HTML 404 NOT found error instead of a JSON response, in that case it gives error "invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value" and the program exits, how can we ignore the error and keep the program running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [`log.Fatal`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal) - by using that function you're explicitly telling it to crash when it encounters an error:

> Fatal is equivalent to Print() followed by a call to os.Exit(1).

"Fatal" means what it says, it kills the process.

Comment: ok, then what can i use to print just the error without a call to os.Exit(1) ?

Comment: As the documentation says, `Fatal` calls `Print` followed by `os.Exit(1)`. So, if you want it without the exit... call `log.Print()`. Or try [reading the documentation of the log package](https://golang.org/pkg/log/).

Comment: ok, tried removing `log.Fatal` but still the program stops automatically .

Comment: one more thing, as you must have noticed in my code i mentioned `// Using err := gives error no new variables on left side of := during compilation` does using just `=` rather than `:=` cause a problem to the program anywhere?

Comment: Yes. The error is correct. Did you have a question about it?

Comment: does using just `=` rather than `:=` cause a problem to the program anywhere?

Comment: I don't know, does it? `=` assigns a value to an existing variable, `=:` assigns a value to a new variable. Consider reading the [Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/) to get a handle on the basic Go syntax.

Comment: i don't think it should cause a problem, so i thought to ask to be on safe side  ..